# VBA as data source for Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I would like to have VBA generate some data for an Excel Pivot table. VBA will then recalulate the data and the pivot will update based on that.

Question: Is it possible to have VBA be a direct data source for the pivot or do I need to write down in a file from VBA and have the pitot refresh itself from there?
The direct data source gives me the advantage that I can create multi-dimensional data and not only a 2D matrix.

I can see I can choose a lot of data sources and I could write some data in one of these formats from VBA.

So for example I could choose to generate an xml file from VBA, and then have a pivot table use that xml file as its source. I guess it would be a bad idea to emulate the OLAP cubes from the SQL Server in VBA!

Damian

Comment: VBA is not a data source in itself, but a programming language used to manipulate data (or objects). You can store data in arrays and such, but that is only available at run-time. The only thing VBA could do is  manipulate existing data and then place it into a range that the pivot table is based on. If you need more help, please provide more information, because your question is 100% clear.

Comment: I added some more comments, I hope it helps?

Answer (score 0):

For OLAP cubes, the Microsoft Excel is a very good viewer, but if you have access to Analysis Server tool, you will prefer use it.

But, Excel can connect to SQL Server by itself. Have you tried? It is in Data menu.